# How to plot Indian Meteorological Sub-Divisions on the map?

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-visualization, geopandas, folium

So, the Indian Meteorological Sub-Divisions are different from the state boundaries. One large state may have multiple Sub-Divisions and a few small states together can for one single Sub-Division. For example the state of Maharashtra has 4 Sub-Divisions where as the 4 states of Nagaland, Manipur, Mizoram and Tripura together form 1 Sub-Division. The problem is that i could not find the list of districts that fall into each Sub-Division. If i do have the district data then it would be easy as in we categorically group districts that are part of the same Sub-Division. I dont know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find geometry here: https://gist.github.com/planemad/d347ad7485344fb0ba4b470721825427

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/planemad/d347ad7485344fb0ba4b470721825427/raw/4c683c9e1c46bc7373dc3df34202080e1a69c6e3/india-district-imd.geojson")
```